# How to crisp up/dehydrate thin slices of porchetta?

Tags: meat, pork

I made a small porchetta this weekend.

I want to slice it as thin as possible and crisp it up (used as topping for soups for example).

I was wondering: what would be the best technique to do that?

Slow oven heat over *long* time? Pan fried on low heat and remove fat?

Comment: I'm not sure it's going to crisp up for you. Porchetta isn't bacon, the outside will get nice and crispy but the majority of it is pork meat, which is more likely just going to dry out.

Comment: If you remove the fat there will not be anything left.

Comment: After the salting of a week and the three weeks of hanging I cannot see how a piece of porchetta has any moisture left to dehydrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely depends on what texture you're going for when you're done, and how much fat there is in the meat that you're curing.

I'll assume that you want crispy, and not the chewy type of dehydrated that you get with beef jerky.

- If the cuts aren't very fatty, and you have the ability to slice the meat *very* thinly, then you could try placing it on wire racks and the low oven approach, and then break it up into flakes to use as garnish.
- If the cut it fatty, then I would treat it more like lardon -- cut into small cubes, and cook in a pan over medium low heat until you've rendered the fat, then continue cooking (possibly turning up the heat) until the meat is crispy.
- If it's not fatty, but you can't slice it thin enough, then I'd go with the lardon approach, but add some oil to fry the meat in.